# Access to apache2 on ubuntu from phone

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, smartphone, wifi

I would like to access my Apache 2 from my smartphone for testing purposes.
I have Apache2 running on Ubuntu.I already checked similar questions here on forum,but I didn't manage to access my site.
On my phone i get "Network problem , site unavailable" error.
I tried to set my ports.conf to listen to *:80 , but i reverted to backup because that didnt work.

edit:from another computer i can access it with the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to access your Ubuntu server from the Internet, which means its firewall should allow connections from outside on port 80 (HTTP), you can easily allow that by running this command as root :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that you'll need to re-run that command each time since IPTables rules aren't persistant across reboots, or change it directly using your distrbution's firewall configuration tool (i'm not sure how Ubuntu does this, but on my Archlinux desktop it's a simple matter of putting your rules into /etc/iptables/iptables.rules and they're automatically loaded at boot by the corresponding systemd "iptables.service" service).

Also if your server is behind a router, you'll need to configure that router to redirect incoming connections on TCP port 80 to the server's private IP address (by "private IP address" I mean the address the server has on your private network, usually something like "192.168.x.x").

Once the firewall and router (if there's one) are both correctly configured, you should be able to access your server via its public IP address (which isn't the same as its "private" IP address if it's behind a router), you can easily get that address by running :

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

on the server (just open a terminal and copy/paste it), the result of that command will be its public IP address.

And also, Stackoverflow is mainly about programming, for more server/network related questions you should go to [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: First of all : apologies for misplaced question.Didn't notice Serverfault before.
Second : that's a problem because i have some lame-a** router,where i can not set such feature. I will go ahead and try updating its firmware.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Usually all routers have basic port forwarding options. Also note that the port forwarding stuff is only needed to access the server from the Internet (from another computer or from the cell phone network), if you just need to access it from the phone that is connected to the same network as the server, then you can forget all the port forwarding stuff - then you should be able to access it via its "private" IP address as long as you're on the same network.

Comment: I can access it that way ( using its private IP ) from another PC on the same network.But my phone ( also on the same network ) does not get access.I tried default Android browser as well as Opera Mini , but no joy.

Comment: If another PC can already access it, then the firewall is already allowing the connection and there's nothing to do on the server itself - are you sure the phone is connected on the same network as your server ? It may very well be that your phone is connected to its cellular network and is actually on the Internet, and not on your private network. If it's connected, can you get its private IP (you can see it in the Wi-Fi settings menu) and try "ping" it from the server (running "ping <ip>" on the server) ?

Comment: I am sure its on the same network,because i manually switch between cellular and wifi.It definitely is on the same network.When i try PING , it gives me like twenty "unreachable" and then one or two results , then again many "unreachable" .... i figure theres problem with reaching my phone.

Comment: The router gets impossible here.Even when i reserve the entire bandwidth for just my phone and my server,the ping doesnt get under two seconds.Unfortunately the router is not my property so i have to stick with it.... sorry for bothering here....

Comment: So basically there's a problem when trying to communicate between the wireless and the wired network... there's not much you can do with that unfortunately, except maybe get closer to the access point, that'll make things better if the issue is a too weak wireless signal. However, if the server is a laptop, you can use it to create a wireless network independent of your current router and connect your phone to it; this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/180734) explains how to use Hostapd on Ubuntu in order to create an access point.

Comment: I am already making my laptop a hotspot :) thanks for all Your help man :) i appreciate it dearly :)